# How to delete the HDFS data in Docker containers

Tags: hadoop, docker

I run hadoop cluster in `Docker` by mount a local folder by `-v`.

Then I login the hadoop cluster and 'cd' to the mount folder and execute `hdfs dfs -put ./data/* input/`. It works.

But my problem is that I cannot delete the data that I copied to `hdfs`. I delete  containers by `docker rm` ,but the data still exist. Now I only can reset Docker and the data can be deleted.

Is there any other solution?

This is my docker info

`➜  hadoop docker info
Containers: 5
 Running: 5
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 1
Server Version: 1.12.3
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 22
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: null bridge host overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: seccomp
Kernel Version: 4.4.27-moby
Operating System: Alpine Linux v3.4
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 5
Total Memory: 11.71 GiB
Name: moby
ID: NPR6:2ZTU:CREI:BHWE:4TQI:KFAC:TZ4P:S5GM:5XUZ:OKBH:NR5C:NI4T
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 56
 Goroutines: 81
 System Time: 2016-11-22T08:10:37.120826598Z
 EventsListeners: 2
Username: chaaaa
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No kernel memory limit support
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8`

Comment: And I cannot find `Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs` in my Mac. Is it normal?

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue. https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/371

> If you can remove all images/containers then:
>
> - Stop Docker.
> - run

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls |awk '{print $2}')
rm -rf ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/*
```

> - Start Docker, you have yours GB back.

Answer (score 0):

To delete data in a HDFS you need to make a similar call like the one you did to put the file, in this case:

```
hdfs dfs -rm ./data/*
```

If there are directories you should add -r

```
hdfs dfs -rm -R ./data/*
```

And finally, by default Hadoop move deleted files/directories to a trash directory, which would be in the home of the hadoop user you're using for this requests, something like `/user/<you>/.Trash/`

**About HDFS**

Usually in the namenode there is some metadata about the structure of the HDFS, like the directories or files in it and where are the blocks forming it stored (Which datanodes). While datanodes will keep blocks of HDFS data, the data stored usually is not usable, since it will usually be just part of the data blocks in the HDFS.

Because of this, all operations with the HDFS are done through the namenode using `hdfs` calls, like `put`, `get`, `rm`, `mkdir`... instead of regular operating system command line tools.

Comment: This should works. But I delete the Docker containers, why the data I copied to it still exist?

Comment: Well, that is not the target of your original question, but it might be related with how you create the containers and the volumes linked to it.

If you also need to know why that happens I suggest you to edit your question to reflect this, also provide more information about how you create the container.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It helps me a lot to know about the HDFS. But would you please tell me that if I delete the containers, is the data I copied deleted?
Thanks very much again!